# WooCommerce get product type after save

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Can you please tell me how can I get product type after product save?

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'nd_update_group_product_attributes_func', 1001, 3 );   

function nd_update_group_product_attributes_func($post_ID, $post, $update)
{

    if($post->post_type == 'product'){

        $childrens   = $post->get_children();
        $product_type = $post->get_type();  /* this will return simple for all product type*/ 


    }

}
```

Even I have "grouped" product type.
$product_type = $post->get_type(); on save_post_product hook will return the "simple" when we first create the product and later on update will return "grouped".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the WooCommerce product object using the function `wc_get_product`

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_product_object_save', 'nd_update_group_product_attributes_func', 10, 2);

function nd_update_group_product_attributes_func($product, $data_store) {

    $product_type = $product->get_type();
    if ($product->is_type('grouped')) {

        $child_product_ids = $product->get_children();
        $all_child_bed_attributes = array();

        foreach ($child_product_ids as $child_product_id) {

            $child_product = wc_get_product($child_product_id);
            $pa_bedrooms = $child_product->get_attribute('pa_bedrooms');
            $all_child_bed_attributes = array_unique(array_merge($all_child_bed_attributes, $pa_bedrooms));
        }
        if ($all_child_bed_attributes) {

            foreach ($all_child_bed_attributes as $bed) {
                wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $bed, 'pa_bedrooms', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The hook `woocommerce_after_product_object_save` can be used here

Comment: Even I have "grouped" product type. 
$product_type = $product->get_type(); on save_post_product hook will return the "simple" when we first create the product and later on update will return "grouped".

Answer (score 0):

if( $_product->is_type( 'simple' ) )
$product->is_type( 'variable' )

Comment: I have tried this as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).